# Kernel Panic and weird behavior

Tags: kernel, crash

About two weeks ago I started experience the weird behavior of my pc. About 5 min or sooner after pc start it's peripherals turn off on both Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7 (running dual boot on separate hdds). Today Windows crashes with blue screen while I was playing in game and after that kernel panic on Linux. I'm a bit surprised with such a combo and ask for help of people that may know what the problem.

[image]

---

Running memtest as suggested I found dozens of errors...

Comment: Probably related to hardware failing; impossible to say what. Bad RAM or bad disk is the most probable cause. BACKUP NOW if you can.

Comment: Assuming that Linux is running on ssd and Windows on hdd it's most likely to be RAM issues, am I right? I has two different RAM planks but with same voltage an clocking. Both are Kingston. Is it damaged plank for some reason or just incompatible pair of planks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the kernel panic you've shown (the Windows one might help as well), I would have to wager that this is a memory / RAM issue.

What you should do for the time being to pinpoint the actual issue:

1. Reboot your machine.
2. When the boot menu shows up (shown below), select the first `Memory Test`.
3. Let it run. Note any errors.

Please post back with any info from the test(s).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for an answer and wait just for a couple of minutes)

Comment: You should let the Memory Test run at least once (one Test, which equates to a lot of passes). It may take a while. A book comes in handy. :)

Comment: @mozite Ouch :(

Comment: I posted a photo of the first errors and now it looks like test has stuck on 9% just after this red mess appears on screen(

Comment: @mozite Unfortunately, you're going to have to buy new RAM sticks and remove the old ones. (Sorry I can't comment on your answer because I don't have enough rep).

Comment: Both of them? Are they incompatible or a sort of broken?)

Comment: @mozite Without RAM details (like what kind of sticks, voltage, etc...), I would wager broken. Although both (incompatible and/or broken is bad). Unfortunately, you're going to have to go shopping. :(

Comment: That's bad news but thank you very much for help! Well, I'll try to run test with them apart of each other - maybe something else will show up) Again thank you)

Comment: No problem! Hope it gets resolved! :)